# How to show images by calling an API inside antd-item-list-container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

When the page loads I'm calling an API to retrieve images saved in the database. Then I want to show those images inside *Modal* in **Antd**. How can i achieve that using below code segment.

```
const MyVehiclePage = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const imageURLS = getAllMediaData();
  }, []);
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="uploadBtn">
          <Upload
            onRemove={removeImage}
            customRequest={handleUpload}
            listType="picture-card"
            onPreview={handlePreview}>
            {fileKeys.length >= 10 ? null : uploadButton}
          </Upload>
        </div>

        {imageURLS.length >= 1 &&
            imageURLS.map((item)=> (
               <Modal
          open={previewOpen}
          title={previewTitle}
          footer={null}
          onCancel={handleCancel}
        >
          <img alt="example" style={{ width: "100%" }} src={item} />
        </Modal>
              />
            ))
          }
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

make a call to your `getAllMediaData` function to fetch the image URLs when the component mounts. then map over the image URLs and display them using the `img` tag. When clicking on an image, the `handlePreview` function is called to open the Modal with the clicked image.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Modal, Upload } from 'antd';

const MyVehiclePage = (props) => {
  const [imageURLS, setImageURLS] = useState([]);
  const [previewOpen, setPreviewOpen] = useState(false);
  const [previewTitle, setPreviewTitle] = useState('');
  const [previewImage, setPreviewImage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMediaData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getAllMediaData();
        setImageURLS(response.data); // Assuming response.data contains the array of image URLs
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching media data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchMediaData();
  }, []);

  const handlePreview = (url) => {
    setPreviewImage(url);
    setPreviewTitle('Image Preview');
    setPreviewOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setPreviewOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="uploadBtn">
        {/* Your Upload component here */}
      </div>

      {imageURLS.length >= 1 &&
        imageURLS.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <img
              alt="example"
              style={{ cursor: 'pointer', width: '100%' }}
              src={item}
              onClick={() => handlePreview(item)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      <Modal
        visible={previewOpen}
        title={previewTitle}
        footer={null}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <img alt="example" style={{ width: '100%' }} src={previewImage} />
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyVehiclePage;
```